# CO Alarm beeps at 6 AM everyday

Tags: electrical

I've seen a question similar to this before and most answers say its because 6 AM is the coldest time of day, but this is incorrect. In northern climates it's very common for detectors to chirp low battery warnings at night (or when away from a vacation home with the heat turned down) and not during the times when the furnace is set to a warmer temperature. Most, in my experience, don't have the "intelligence" to store a low battery warning and reset it when the battery is changed. It's a continuous voltage monitor and that's it. So is there any other explanation?

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning for why the cool time of day explanation is faulty.

Comment: Is this battery-only or AC-powered with battery backup?

Comment: What happens if you program your furnace to warm the house at, say,  5AM and keep it warm?

Comment: Sorry im so late on your question. For your first, it is battery only, and for your second I'm not sure, I did replace the batteries and the beeping stopped, and i do believe it has something to do with the cold weather

Answer (score 4):

Co detectors last about 10 years and most will chirp to indicate an "end of life" senario.

Comment: Yup- this is what mine did. There should be a sticker somewhere on your alarm- maybe in the battery compartment -  that provides the manufacture and/or end of life date.

Comment: For future readers, many detectors now have a 7-year lifespan. As mentioned above, check the device for the end of life date.

Comment: My CO2 detector is two years old

Answer (score 1):

### Chilly batteries don't work so well

The electrochemical reactions that make batteries, well, tick slow down in cooler temperatures.  This is where the old saw about storing batteries in the fridge to extend their shelf life comes from, and it also means that batteries aren't as good at supplying current when they are cold.  As a result of that latter fact, it's possible for a marginal battery to sag under load when cold to the point the low battery detection goes off, but be fine when warmer and able to supply sufficient current for the electronics to run without causing the voltage to sag.

Comment: Yes, this was my initial thought. Two questions though. One, why does it only last for a couple minutes then? I know 6 AM is the coldest point of the day, but why wouldnt it beep for longer? And two, why does it beep every 10 seconds? Doesn't it usually beep every 15? I should also add this was in July, and I live in LA, would it really be cold enough then?

Comment: @HuCooper -- not sure on either